# Switch mode from BLE to Bluetooth Classic and back

Tags: bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy

I have two Bluetooth 4.0 dual mode devices. Is it possible to do the following
1) Connect via BLE to transfer state information
2) Switch connection to Bluetooth Classic to transfer large file (to be done without user interaction)
3) Back to BLE

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is there a programming question?

Comment: Perhaps - but it would really depend on the devices, their Bluetooth/BLE software stacks, and the precise requirements.  For example, do you have to maintain the BLE connection while performing the blutooth transfer?

Comment: All of the content available via BLE is supposed to be available via "classic" bluetooth.  If both devices support "classic" bluetooth than you should just stay with that connection.  You haven't really stated why you need to switch connections, so no one will be able to address that.